# Symfony 4 + graylog + console errors

Tags: symfony, exception, logging, graylog

I have a web application and I need to write exceptions to graylog. I asked sysadmins and they told me to just throw exception messages to stdout and it will be enough, but this way doesn't work for me.

Meanwhile I have next door virtualhost with native PHP app which just have `error_reporting = E_ALL` and `display_errors = 1` and these settings are enough, and graylog see these errors, but not mine (I'm using Symfony 4 + Monolog) in the Monolog config I have almost the default settings

```
main:
    type:                fingers_crossed
    level:               debug
    path:                'php://stdout'
```

If I change path from stdout to logfilename it works ok, but I need to see my logs in graylog, not in a file. Unfortunately I haven't got the graylog configs, the Symfony application ones only.

Comment: Hi, you just need to use gelf here https://github.com/bzikarsky/gelf-php

Comment: have added this to my composer.json         "graylog2/gelf-php": "0.1.*",  and this to services.yaml 
   
    monolog.gelf_handler:
      class: Monolog\Handler\GelfHandler
      arguments: ['@gelf.publisher']

    gelf.publisher:
      class: Gelf\Publisher
      arguments: ['@gelf.ignore_error_transport']

    gelf.ignore_error_transport:
      class: Gelf\Transport\IgnoreErrorTransportWrapper
      arguments: ['@gelf.transport']

    gelf.transport:
      class: Gelf\Transport\UdpTransport and this to monolog.yaml

Comment: monolog:
        graylog:
            type: service
            id: monolog.gelf_handler
            level: debug

Comment: And now im getting error Attempted to load class "Publisher" from namespace "Gelf".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Comment: Fixed this issue, what should i do next?